# How to get a list of filterable options from Autofilter in Powershell?

Tags: excel, powershell, filter

I'm using powershell to automate some excel manipulation.

I have no issues toggling the Autofilter on my columns, as well as selecting a single value out.

But I cannot use the Filters property to get a collection of the items in the Autofilter object. My suspicion is that I have no handle for the actual Autofilter object.

The problem is, carrying out an AutoFilter(value1, criteria1) on a worksheet Range object returns a boolean.

```
> $var1 = $ageVerSource.Worksheets.Item(1).Range($variableRepresetingTheRangeIMinterestedIn).EntireColumn.AutoFilter(1,"stringexample")

> $var1

True
```

...what is the correct procedure on getting the list of Filter options from an Autofilter result in Powershell?

Kind Regards

Comment: There's no builtin public function to retrieve all possible criteria. You could enumerate all values in the range/column and pipe through `|sort -uniq` to build a list of valid criteria

Comment: Thanks. I am currently using $var1 | Sort-Object | Get-Unique which can take a while, is this the best that's available? Add to that it takes the first row which has my column header. I have up to 50k rows. If this was done through VBA and the list was retrieved from a valid AutoFilter object, how long would it take in comparison?

Comment: As mentioned above, there's no builtin function to retrieve the possible criteria, in VBA you'd have to implement the same algorithm. You could create a `[HashSet[int]]`, add all values to it and sort the resulting set, might be slightly faster than `|Sort-Object |Get-Unique`

Comment: " 
As mentioned above, there's no builtin function to retrieve the possible criteria, in VBA you'd have to implement the same algorithm." - Wait, so what's the point of the Filters property of the Autofilter object then? The documentation here https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff194617.aspx states it's mean to "return a collection of individual column filters." What does this mean?

Comment: The Filters property return objects that represent filters already applied, ie. the criteria, (optional) operator and state of a given filter. You can easily inspect this yourself with `$ageVerSource.Worksheets.Item(1).AutoFilter.Filters`. I think you're confusing "Filter" and "Valid criteria" here

Comment: Many thanks for clarifying this - you've ended about 6 hours of struggling.

Comment: My distinct pleasure :)